# Async method followed by a parallelly executed method in Java 8

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, java.util.concurrent

After spending the day of learning about the java Concurrency API, I still dont quite get how could I create the following functionality with the help of CompletableFuture and ExecutorService classes:

When I get a request on my REST endpoint I need to:

1. Start an asynchronous task (includes DB query, filtering, etc.), which will give me a list of String URLs at the end
2. In the meanwhile, responde back to the REST caller with HTTP OK, that the request was received, I'm working on it
3. When the asynchronous task is finished, I need to send HTTP requests (with the payload, the REST caller gave me) to the URLs I    got from the job. At most the number of URLs would be around a 100,    so I need these to happen in parallel.
4. Ideally I have some syncronized counter which counts how many of the http requests were a success/fail, and I can send this information back to the REST caller (the URL I need to send it back    to is provided inside the request payload).

I have the building blocks (methods like: getMatchingObjectsFromDB(callerPayload), getURLs(resultOfgetMachingObjects), sendHttpRequest(Url, methodType), etc...) written for these already, I just cant quite figure out how to tie step 1 and step 3 together. I would use `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` for step 1, then I would need the `CompletableFuture.thenComponse` method to start step 3, but it's not clear to me how parallelism can be done with this API. It is rather intuitive with `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();` though, which creates a thread pool based on how much processing power is available and the tasks can be submitted via the `invokeAll()` method.

How can I use `CompletableFuture`and `ExecutorService` together? Or how can I guarantee parallel execution of a list of tasks with `CompletableFuture`? Demonstrating code snippet would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since you mention REST, are you using some framework like Spring Boot or DropWizard? Because depending on the framework/environment, there could be different options to achieve what you ask.

Comment: I'm using Jersey 2 with Hibernate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `join()` to wait for all thread finish.

Create `Map<String, Boolean> result` to store your request result.

In your controller:

```
public void yourControllerMethod() {

  CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> yourServiceMethod());
}
```

In your service:

```
// Execute your logic to get List<String> urls

List<CompletableFuture> futures = urls.stream().map(v -> 
 CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(url -> requestUrl(url))
           .thenAcceptAsync(requestResult -> result.put(url, true or false))
).collect(toList()); // You have list of completeable future here
```

Then use `.join()` to wait for all thread (Remember that your service are executed in its own thread already)

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();
```

Then you can determine which one success/fail by accessing `result` map

**Edit**

Please post your proceduce code so that other may understand you also.

I've read your code and here are the needed modification:

> When this for loop was not commented out, the receiver webserver got
>   the same request twice,
>         I dont understand the purpose of this for loop.

Sorry in my previous answer, I did not clean it up. That's just a temporary idea on my head that I forgot to remove at the end :D

Just remove it from your code

> // allOf() only accepts arrays, so the List needed to be converted
>       /* The code never gets over this part (I know allOf() is a blocking call), even long after when the receiver got the HTTP request
>
> ```
>    with the correct payload. I'm not sure yet where exactly the code gets stuck */
> ```

Your map should be a `ConcurrentHashMap` because you're modifying it concurrently later.

```
Map<String, Boolean> result = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

If your code still does not work as expected, I suggest to remove the `parallelStream()` part.

`CompletableFuture` and `parallelStream` use common forkjoin pool. I think the pool is exhausted.

And you should create your own pool for your `CompletableFuture`:

```
Executor pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

And execute your request using that pool:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(YOURTASK, pool).thenAcceptAsync(Yourtask, pool)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm only able to dissect and try this out tomorrow, I will report back then, with potential questions/accepted answer :)

Comment: I had to write a bunch of code today on the client side to be able to test this, but when I did, things only worked halfway. So far there was only 1 URL in the database, where the request needed to be sent. Detailed code snippets are here: https://pastebin.com/kgiU5CWa

I'm not sure I implemented your code correctly.

Comment: I will check now

Comment: It looks like I'm having trouble converting the stream to an array for allOf(). If I just simply call toArray() on the stream and try to manually cast the results, the asynctask will execute (client will get the http request), but I will get a "ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture". If I use toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new), I get no exception, but the join() has no effect basically, the HTTP request will not be sent at all. Both ways, the result map is empty, not sure how to proceed at the moment.

Comment: Why do you know the Http is not requested? Btw, try to split to two part, collect to List then convert to array like my first suggesttion.

Comment: Because: 1) the client never receives the request 2) in debug mode, If I have a breakpoint at the start of sendRequest() method, it never stops there.
I already tried stream->array, stream->list->array and list->array conversions with the for loop version, none of them worked :/

Comment: The problem probably not related to the array conversion, since I tried to pass just a single Future to allOf() and had the same thing happen (nothing happening, it doesnt matter if I call join() or get() on the allOf() future.

Comment: Remove the .parallel part

Comment: The problem is there

Comment: I already did that a while ago, but I just found out the static sendRequest method was not called because I used the synchronized keyword on it. Now it works. Once I cleanup the code, and try it out with more urls, I'll post an answer with it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok. Good luck:)

Comment: Any idea btw why was the synchronized keyword a problem? :D There wasnt even multiple threads trying to call sendRequest yet. I'm confused. I only deleted it, because I saw my CompletableFuture test project with System.out.print method bodies did not use it, and that was working :D

Comment: It's straightforward. If you use sychronized, your method can be executed by only one thread at a time. But we use completableFuture (internally a thread pool) to execute multiple task at parallel. So it blocks other thread and only let one executed at a time

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completion here is the relevant parts of the code, after clean-up and testing (thanks to Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn):

Rest controller class:

```
@POST
@Path("publish")
public Response publishEvent(PublishEvent eventPublished) {
    /*
        Payload verification, etc.
    */

    //First send the event to the right subscribers, then send the resulting hashmap<String url, Boolean subscriberGotTheRequest> back to the publisher
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> EventHandlerService.propagateEvent(eventPublished)).thenAccept(map -> {
      if (eventPublished.getDeliveryCompleteUri() != null) {
        String callbackUrl = Utility
            .getUri(eventPublished.getSource().getAddress(), eventPublished.getSource().getPort(), eventPublished.getDeliveryCompleteUri(), isSecure,
                    false);
        try {
          Utility.sendRequest(callbackUrl, "POST", map);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
          log.error("Callback after event publishing failed at: " + callbackUrl);
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });

    //return OK while the event publishing happens in async
    return Response.status(Status.OK).build();
}
```

Service class:

```
private static List<EventFilter> getMatchingEventFilters(PublishEvent pe) {
    //query the database, filter the results based on the method argument
}

private static boolean sendRequest(String url, Event event) {
    //send the HTTP request to the given URL, with the given Event payload, return true if the response is positive (status code starts with 2), false otherwise
}

static Map<String, Boolean> propagateEvent(PublishEvent eventPublished) {
    // Get the event relevant filters from the DB
    List<EventFilter> filters = getMatchingEventFilters(eventPublished);
    // Create the URLs from the filters
    List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
    for (EventFilter filter : filters) {
      String url;
      try {
        boolean isSecure = filter.getConsumer().getAuthenticationInfo() != null;
        url = Utility.getUri(filter.getConsumer().getAddress(), filter.getPort(), filter.getNotifyUri(), isSecure, false);
      } catch (ArrowheadException | NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        continue;
      }
      urls.add(url);
    }

    Map<String, Boolean> result = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    Stream<CompletableFuture> stream = urls.stream().map(url -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> sendRequest(url, eventPublished.getEvent()))
                                                                                 .thenAcceptAsync(published -> result.put(url, published)));
    CompletableFuture.allOf(stream.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join();
    log.info("Event published to " + urls.size() + " subscribers.");
    return result;
}
```

Debugging this was a bit harder than usual, sometimes the code just magically stopped. To fix this, I only put code parts into the async task which was absolutely necessary, and I made sure the code in the task was using thread-safe stuff. Also I was a dumb-dumb at first, and my methods inside the `EventHandlerService.class` used the `synchronized` keyword, which resulted in the CompletableFuture inside the Service class method not executing, since it uses a thread pool by default.

> A piece of logic marked with synchronized becomes a synchronized block, allowing only one thread to execute at any given time.